# Blurring image with RGB values without convolving it with a kernel

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, rgb, gaussianblur

I'm using an app for face redaction that doesn't allow access to the source code but only allows me to pass pixel values for red, green and blue channel upon which it creates a matrix with the same average RGB values for every ROI pixel value. For eg. if I give Red=32,Blue=123 and Green=233 it will assign these RGB values for every pixel of the ROI and then draws a colored patch on the face.

So I was wondering is there a general combination of RGB values of a pixel to distort it and make it look like it's blurred. I can also set the opacity value in the app.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understood what the app does, does it paint the faces with the color you pass?

Comment: Do you have access to each pixel or can you only pass a single set of values? If that's all you can do then you could make a solid gray box and play with the opacity. But no matter what you are stuck with a solid color in that case. Values for gray are 105,105,105. Increase to make darker.